# Earned value management with ressources of type "Cost"

Tags: cost-management, evm

I'm working on project management with the client-side manager. We manage the cost with cost type ressources as we only know how much we are going to pay for each task and not how many hours of work and how much material are put into it.

My question is, when I use this type of ressources, why does MS Project not calculate EV, PV, etc. ? why does it only show EAC and BAC ?

Microsoft Project don't automatically calculate the EV and other variables:
[image: EV interface]

This capture shows how my cost type resources are entered:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The two variables you say you don't know are required to calculate PV, or BCWS, the cumulative sum of which is your BAC.  Without this value, you cannot arrive at your EV, or BCWP.

The question becomes, why can't you arrive at your planning values? If you have your BAC, how did you arrive at that without knowing its parts?

Comment: I suspect this caused by the fact that none of my resource are of type  "Work". All are Cost resources. It may be as if work costs nothing (correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: It doesn't matter. You need a planning value for each type of resource, no matter type. For example, an airline ticket is a cost resource. At planning time I may not know exact cost but will choose a value to set my budget, eg, $800. Actual cost may be better or worse.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand why am I getting zeroes everywhere in the earned value management table.